# HTML CSS Problem Space between Get and started makes get on the first line and started on the second

Tags: html, css, web

Hi so I am having a problem with my website
Where my Get Started
comes like
GetStarted
[image]

and if i add a space between Get and started
then its like Get on the first line and started on the second
[image]

I have tried using display inlineblock in my css code and also decreasing my font size

Here is the code--

CSS-

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face{
    src: url(/fonts/Coiny-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: Coiny;
}

body, html{
    background-image: url(/img/BackGround.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.name{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Coiny;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    
    color: black;
}

.centre{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 760px;
}

h2 a{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: purple;
    background-color: purple;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.description{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 22.5px;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

li a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Coiny;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}


a{
    border-color: purple ;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 12px;

}

nav li a {
    border-color: purple;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.name2{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    
    color: black;
}
```

HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pacific</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="name2"><strong>Pacific</strong></li>
                <li><a href="/index.html"> <strong>Home</strong> </a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/about.html"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/contacts.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </h1>
        
    </nav>
    <h1 class="name">Pacific</h1>
    <h2 class="centre"> <a href="/html/login.html"><strong>GetStarted</strong> </a></h2>
    <div>
    <p class="description"> <strong>
    Get started with pacific and manage <br>
    your projects better, Let's say you <br>
    are writing an essay for your school <br>
    or sending an important email to    <br>
    your boss.Look up the best <br>
    words to use and when to <br>
    use, Pacific corrects imperfect grammer and <br>
    spelling mistakes has a translation tool,<br>
    Paragraph tool,Bold,Italic etc <br>
    Get Started with Pacific Right Now! <br>  </strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html"> <strong>Home</strong> </a></li>
        <li><a href="/html/about.html"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/html/contacts.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ps- I want Get Started in the same line I forgot to put this part in the question

Comment: Absolute positioning makes the width calculation happen by “shrink-to-fit” here, that appears to be what’s causing this. If you don’t ever need the text to break into multiple lines, then set `white-space: pre` for the link or the strong inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick work around you can do this

```
<strong>Get&nbsp;Started</strong>
```

But do apply propper css in future .

> By applying white-space: pre; as mentioned in @CBroe comment  or
> white-space: nowrap; in css you can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the padding-left on .centre class

```
.centre{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 758px;
}
```

Alternatively You could set the flex-wrap to noWrap.

```
.centre{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 760px;
}
```

One other thing to adjust is width of the .centre class

```
.centre{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 760px;
  width: <insert px or rem amount here>
}
```

One last bit of advice, Use a browser (firefox and/or chrome) with the ability to inspect and play with dom. This way you can play with many different solutions quickly and arrive at a solution that works for you. Good luck and happy hacking!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good question.